# Heroku + MEAN Stack Error: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack

I'm following this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api) on from Heroku on building a MEAN Stack Contact APP and I'm running into some odd error! While my app is working fine once deployed, the app fails to connect to Mongodb when I run it locally. The error I'm getting is:

> url.js:88
>       throw new TypeError('Parameter "url" must be a string, not ' + typeof url);
>       
> ^
>
> TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
>       
> at Url.parse (url.js:88:11)
>       
> at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:82:5)
>       
> at module.exports (/Users/Ananda/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:15:23)
>       
> at connect (/Users/Ananda/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:480:16)
>       
> at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/Ananda/mean-contactlist/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:244:3)
>       
> at Object. (/Users/Ananda/mean-contactlist/server.js:17:21)
>       
> at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       
> at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

From my understanding when I start the app with "node server" it can't find the mongodb database url ... Just not sure why since it finds it just fine when run on heroku. What can I do to run this app locally as well? They have the full app on [Github](https://github.com/chrisckchang/mean-contactlist). I cloned it as well and tried running it locally and received the error. Why is it working when deployed but not locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the mongo client is using an environment variable that is defined in the remote server but not locally. You could just use a default value whenever the MONGODB_URI is not defined (in server.js):

```
// Connect to the database before starting the application server. 
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myLocalDb', function (err, database) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
```

In this case your local MongoDB must be running and a database called myLocalDb will be created when you create a new user.

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the code, you could just declare a local value to MONGODB_URI:

```
set MONGODB_URI='mongodb://localhost:27017/myLocalDb'
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way of fixing this error and connecting to your MongoDB database from mLab is by setting up an environment path manually on your computer.
Name your **environment variable** `MONGODB_URI` and paste your MongoDB uri from mLab into the input of your **variable value** `mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds131687.mlab.com:31687/example`. Save and restart your program.
To verify if the environment path was saved successfully on node mode run

```
console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI)
```

You would see the uri of your mLab db logged to your console.

[How to set up an environment path on windows](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

[How to set up an environment path on Mac](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/)